# Send Text message in MobileConnect using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Below code is not working, I need to take number from Ampscript and then pass that number here and send text message to registrants. I'm placing this scripts in processing page script tag. Is this the correct?

```
<script language=javascript runat=server><br>
    Platform.Load("core", "1");<br>
 //var phoneNumber = Variable.GetValue("@MobileFinal");<br>
  var phoneNumber = "61556465455";<br>

POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken<br>
Content-Type: application/json<br>
{<br>
  "clientId": "qefdskjfhasjfhsdaifuuij",<br>
  "clientSecret": "asdfuh2u3i4h23iurfhweqf"<br>
}<br><br>
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/ujheyYYI/send<br>
Content-Type: application/json<br>
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN<br>
{<br>
    "mobileNumbers": [<br>
    phoneNumber<br>
    ],<br>
    "Subscribe": true,<br>
    "Resubscribe": true,<br>
    "Override": true,<br>
    "messageText": "Welcome",<br>
}<br>
</script><br>
```

Comment: Could you please explain the use case of your script here? Also, if you're placing this in a script tag in a cloudpage this exposes your clientid and clientsecret. If you could explain a high-level use case, then we might be able to find a proper solution.

Comment: We have cloud Registration page, they are placing that in the website. Whenever anyone register from cloud Registration page, they should get text message on mobile as "Thanks for registering". We are inserting record to DE from cloud page only by using AMPSCRIPT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, I had to rewrite the whole code and I did the test. The code is now working and triggers an SMS when ran through a cloudpage.

A couple of considerations:

- Please create a keyword and change it within the payload as `keyword` is mandatory.
- The Resubscribe is set as `true` which means users will be receiving SMS even if they have opted out unless the SMS is a service/transactional type. I'd recommend to set it to `false` if it is marketing SMS.

  `%%[SET @MobileFinal = "614xxxxxxxx"]%%
  <script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("core", "1");
  var mobileNumber = Variable.GetValue("@MobileFinal");
  var mobileNumberList = [];
  mobileNumberList[0] = mobileNumber;
  var mobileNumbers = Stringify(mobileNumberList);`

  `//Request accesstoken
  var url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken';
  var contentType = 'application/json';
  var client_id = 'your_client_id'
  var client_secret = 'your_client_secret'
  var payload = '{"clientId":"CLIENT_ID","clientSecret":"CLIENT_SECRET"}';
  payload = payload.replace('CLIENT_ID', client_id);
  payload = payload.replace('CLIENT_SECRET', client_secret);`

  `var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
  var response = eval("(function(){return " + result.Response + ";})()");
  var accessToken = response.accessToken;`

  `//Triggered SMS
  url = 'http://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/ujheyYYI/send';
  contentType = 'application/json';
  payload = '{"mobileNumbers":MOBILENUMBERS,"Subscribe":true,"Resubscribe":true,"keyword":"TEST","messageText": "Welcome","Override": "true"}';
  payload = payload.replace('MOBILENUMBERS', mobileNumbers);
  var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
  var headerValues = ['Bearer ' + accessToken];
  result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
  </script>`

Reference: [**Send SMS**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm)

Comment: Can you please accept the solution and upvote my post? Cheers

Comment: I did accept the solution, I couldn't able to upvote..